# How to use IP instead of localhost

Tags: apache, ip, wamp, ip-address

I am using Windows server 2008 and installed wamp on it. Now I want to share the local link with client using same network.
Instead of [localhost], I am trying [server_ip_address]. but it's giving me  error.
I want to use it as 192.168.30.1 but not able access this.
I also put the wamp online and restart the server. I m able use the ip from my m/c only. If I use this link from another m/c then its giving following error

```
URL   http://192.168.5.12:8080 
Error The connection has timed out
```

Comment: replacing localhost by ip address should work with same network.

Comment: I knw what to use it..here things is if I use it as http://192.168.5.12:8080/ then its giving me error

Comment: Are you running a Firewall on the PC running Apache? If so you will need to set that up to allow incomming connections on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the Server from your clients with url like,

```
http://server ip address : port
```

Your Local clients and your Local server must be connected in a LAN network.

Comment: Yes all m/c are connected via LAN n/w

Comment: 8080 is the default port number for oracle, tomcat and other server software. If you run both ,you need to enter some different port number.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows firewall settings. Check by turning off the private network  firewall